# cpanel cron git push not working

Tags: git, cron, bitbucket, cpanel, git-push

I have this command in a script and then I run it through cpanel cron.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/somesite/public_html && git add . && git commit -m "Backup `date +%d%m%Y_%H%M`" && git push;
```

In log I get the following response:

```
[master 06b7cb4] Backup 12032017_2221
 2 files changed, 107 insertions(+), 147 deletions(-)
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

If I run the same command in terminal eveyrthing is ok but through cron the push does not happen.

Comment: This user would need an ssh private key installed, and it would need to **not** be passphrase-protected. And that same key would need to be valid on the server side. Are all of those things true?

Comment: ssh key exist, ssh agent is running and has the key, the public key is added to bitbucket. To what user you refer? This key and cron are created in cpanel. thx for the help btw

Comment: I'm referring to whatever user runs the cron job. I'm not familiar with cpanel, but cron jobs don't normally have access to ssh-agent.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you to achieve what you want:

https://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/how-to-specify-an-ssh-key-file-with-the-git-command/

Then you just have to adapt your bash script that is supposed to run within the cron job